# If i can ping a server does that mean it's switched on?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, ping

I think the question says it all, if I ping a server and access it using \server\c$ and get a response does that mean that server is on?

Comment: Q: if I ping a server and access it using \server\c$ and get a response does that mean that server is on? A: Yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can ping a server, that means the box is online and able to respond to ping requests. This does not guarantee that the other services on the box are up and running, but the box does need to be on and have network access to respond to ping requests.

Comment: unless you ping a ILO port of a server, then the server can actually be OFF, but must be connected to power. otherwise I agree with answer over